# Custom marker types in SSRS maps

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder, reporting-services-map

I'm trying to integrate my own markers as pointers on my map. The defaults of circle, rectangle diamond etc... are not what I need and I'm looking for arrow symbols instead. Ideally the popular Microsoft wingdings arrows. I'm surprised simple arrows are not on the default list, I'd thought there would be many a need to indicate a rise or fall with any numeric data on a map.

I would like to solve this with an expression to force an arrow icon as a marker, can this be done by using it's character code etc..? I'm using SSDT to design the report.

Alternatively I'll just have to do this in paint and upload via the image import.

**Food For Thought**

I see they've done a great job in making the map process easy to set up, but when it comes to customisation from the norm it is extremely difficult.

TechNet: Understanding Marker type Rules:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240825.aspx
As you can see from the link (Which is one example as not to swarm this post with links) Microsoft make no mention of image upload or Expression input for maps. This I find is one example, the maps are great, but I feel it's difficult to get documented resources to further customise my report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an image of an arrow for your custom marker, and you will still be able to change other attributes of it (size, transparency, etc).

If you use a custom image marker, you may run into problems where Visual Studio fails to render the map in design mode from time to time - it's incredibly annoying, so I find it best to drop in the custom images as the very last thing I do when building a map (just use a circle marker or something in the interim).

Comment: Thanks Kyzen, I did think it was going to be down that route either way. What's the point of having an input expression next to marker type anyway? when you have colour and size rules. Is there something fancy in Microsoft Basic I'm missing O.o

Comment: You might want to use different markers based on conditional logic - a happy face if customer feedback is good in this city, a frowny face if they're unhappy in another, etc.  A recent project I worked on had 6 different potential transparency values, 10 colors, 3 sizes, and 8 different marker types.  If you think about it, with maps, you don't have the X/Y axis to help explain your data that you do with traditional charts, so every little thing we can do to add another visualization of a metric helps with maps/

Comment: epic Kyzen! Shame TechNet cannot divulge this information, definitely something I would like to go down but I've bypassed my problem by using multiple layers with data filters on, and giving individual sizes and colours to different data sets. Happy bank holiday if your from the UK!